# How to deal with semi-discrete regressors?

Tags: multiple-regression, normalization, discrete-data

I've aggregated a dataset based on some research I've done regarding Battery Electric Vehicles. Three of my regressors however are throwing me off: Available BEV models in the market, Estimated Average BEV purchase price, and Estimated_Average_purchased_BEV_range. Because these numbers didn't change very often from quarter to quarter, I get QQ-plots that look step-like. I tried including an image, but I'm guessing I can't post images just yet.

From my reading, it seems like normalizing discrete variables isn't necessary. I don't think these are truly discrete variables, but since they resemble them should I treat them as such?

Thank you, and sorry that I'm terribly confused!

Comment: What type of model are you planning on using to answer your research question?

Comment: I was thinking initially that it would be linear regression, but I've discovered that since my dependent variable is a ratio (BEV market share) it might need to be logistic.

Comment: Logistic regression is used for analyzing  binary outcome variables or binomial outcome variables. If your ratio is not obtained by diving two counts, you may need to use something like beta regression.

Comment: My dependent variable is simply the ratio of Battery Electric Vehicle registrations to total market vehicle registrations. A study exactly the same as mine stated that logit transformation was needed on BEV market share (dependent variable) due to the distribution being skewed. Hence, I examined my DV distribution and found that it was also skewed to the right. Upon reading relevant literature my state of confusion sort of led me here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I also forgot to include my model earlier: BEV Market Share = Beta0 + BEVs Registered +  Cumulative Charging Stations + Tax Credit Inventive Available (Dummy Variable) +  BEV Models available In Market +  Estimated Average Registered BEV Purchase Price +  Estimated Average Registered BEV Range + Estimated Average Registered BEV Battery Technology Ratio

Answer (score 1):

Regression analysis is undertaken conditional on the regressors, so it is not really a problem what distribution these values have.  If they are bunched into groups of values that recur over multiple periods, that is fine.  Regression can accommodate continuous regressors with unique values, or discrete regressors, or binary regressors, and even a fixed column of ones for the intercept term.

Depending on the full set of regressors, the presence of one or more regressors which recur at the same values may lead to some bunching on the regressor axes in your diagnostic plots; that does not invalidate the regression or change the interpretation of the plots.  However, it would be strange to see *exact* step-like behaviour in the QQ plots, since this plot compares the empirical quantiles of the *residuals* to their assumed model form.  The residuals are affected both by the regressors but also by the response variable, so if you are getting stepping behaviour in this plot, it is likely to be because you have a *response variable* that is also taking on the same value over multiple periods.  (This would be something worth checking.)  If this is the case then it falsifies the assumption of independent normally distributed error terms, but your regression results might be robust to this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe additional information might help in seeing if I should normalize. My dataset follows a quarterly timeline, because of available data for vehicle registrations and charging stations in the 16 Bundeslaender (states). The rest of my regressors however are all on the national level...hence each one of these observations recurs for every state. Most new BEV models are added in the same quarter of every year, so estimated figures which rely on these models (range, price, etc.) typically only change annually. My data spans 6 years and one quarter, so 400 observations.